# How to filter entities in ngrx?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I created a ngrx entity service:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ProductsDataService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<{ id, name, isActive }> {
  actives$ = this.entities$.pipe(filter(e => e.isActive); <------ but e is an Array!
```

I want to filter by `isActive === true`.

But the problem I get `e` as array.. so I can't do filter.

I can do `.pipe(map(e => e.filter(ee => ee.isActive)))` but this solution is not feel right because it takes two operations in one method (`map`).

Any idea how to do it by ngrx/rxjs way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map function is the correct way to do it:

```
 this.entities$.pipe(map(e => e.filter(...));
```

Filter is here to filter the data stream but not to filter the data itself, i.e. Emit values that pass the provided condition (reference: learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter). In other words deciding whether the data flow should work for specific condition only.

A quick example:

```
x.pipe(filter(num => num === 2)).subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

will print only when 2 is emitted from x.

Comment: I had the same confusion when I started using rxjs.  In the context of pipe, the operators map and filter operate on the stream, not on the arrays getting passed into the stream.  So `map` allows you to change the array into something else.  So you want to use rxjs `map` to change the array into a different array, and call js `Array.filter()` on the mapped object to change the array to one that has only active items for the stream output.